# How to reduce the time complexity of my O(N^2) C-index function?

Tags: performance, algorithm, matlab, matrix, time

I have the following function (in Matlab) which will calculate the concordance index for a given set of predictions and observed values:

```
function civalue = CI(predval)
% FUNCTION civalue = CI(predval)
%
% DESCRIPTION: 
% - This function will calculate the concordance index. Not suitable for
% big vectors. O(n^2) time function. 
%
% INPUTS: 
% 'predval' a n-by-2 matrix, where the first column consists of the
% prediction values and the second column the actual label values. 
%
% OUTPUT: 
% 'civalue' the CI-value.

N = 0;
hSum = 0;

for i = 1:size(predval, 1)

    yi_pred = predval(i, 1);
    yi_val = predval(i, 2);
    for j = i+1:size(predval, 1)
        yj_pred = predval(j, 1);
        yj_val = predval(j, 2);
        if yi_val ~= yj_val
            N = N + 1;
            if  (yi_pred < yj_pred && yi_val < yj_val) || (yi_pred > yj_pred && yi_val > yj_val) % Order correct
                hSum = hSum + 1;
            elseif (yi_pred < yj_pred && yi_val > yj_val) || (yi_pred > yj_pred && yi_val < yj_val) % Order opposite 
                hSum = hSum + 0;
            elseif yi_pred == yj_pred % Random
                hSum = hSum + 0.5;
            end
        end
    end

end

civalue = hSum / N;
```

My function has a time complexity of O(N^2). The idea of the code is to do pairwise comparisons between data points. Any ideas how I could reduce the time complexity of my code?

The idea behind the CI-value or C-index, is to measure how well a prediction model was able to rank data points into correct order. What you give to this function is a set of observed values X and their corresponding predictions Y. The function will do the ranking comparison between data points that have different observed values, because they obviously have a ranking.

For example, lets say you have a two observed values for some variable, e.g. stock price: P1 = 5$, P2 = 7$

Now we create a model that will try to predict the stock prices. Lets say we builded our model and tested its ability to predict the stock price and for the two data points P1, P2 it predicted the values Y1 = 5.5$ and Y2 = 8$.

Now you can see that the model got the ORDER correct, P1 < P2 && Y1 < Y2 but not the absolute value. This is useful when we need to make selections between a set of alternatives, e.g. which stock should I buy that will increase in value most etc.

Thank you for all help! Please let me know if you need any more information etc. :)

Here is the comparison between my own and Martin's implementation:

[image]

Comment: Can you define what exactly are you trying to calculate, I am not sure I am familiar with the CI-value term

Comment: @amit I added some explanation for the C-index, does it help?

Comment: What are the typical datasizes for `predval`?

Comment: @Divakar Hi, it can have matrices with n-by-2 size, with n being arbitrary. In my applications I have had matrices of size 50-by-2, 12000-by-2, 1100-by-2, etc. But we have also applications with 1,000,000-by-2 matrices. The main reason I want to reduce the time complexity is because I'm calling this function for M times and even if the whole one iteration calculation takes 1 second its still very slow if I have many experiments (big M) and I have to wait for hours...

Comment: Just curious, do you have a NVIDIA GPU at your disposal? Would be interesting to speed it up with one of them.

Comment: Sorry @Divakar I think I don't :( I have another computer, where I might have, but I can only check it a bit later.

Comment: If you have, you can do this at the start - `predval = gpuArray(predval);` and then use my code. Otherwise, Martin's answer here looks pretty fast to me and could be accepted.

Comment: Thank you @Divakar for the advice =) I will test both of them and accept the one that gives me faster results. Huge thank you to both of you! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can significantly improve the run-time by vectorizing the inner loop. The code below can be optimized further (at the expense of legibility). On my machine, using random input, the code runs about 50x faster and produces the same results. (Random input is probably a bad test-case, as the `==` branches will never execute)

```
N = 0;
hSum = 0;
for i = 1:size(predval, 1)

    yi_pred = predval(i, 1);
    yi_val = predval(i, 2);
    yj_pred = predval(i+1:end,1);
    yj_val = predval(i+1:end,2);
    idxs = yi_val ~= yj_val;
    N = N + sum(idxs);

    yj_pred = yj_pred(idxs); % redefined to make the next lines prettier
    yj_val = yj_val(idxs); 
    hSum = hSum + sum((yi_pred < yj_pred & yi_val < yj_val) | ...
        (yi_pred > yj_pred & yi_val > yj_val)); % Order correct
    hSum = hSum + 0.5*sum(yi_pred == yj_pred); % Order random
end
```

The complexity of the function is still O(n^2), though.

Comment: This is fast indeed! Good job.

Comment: Hi @MartinJ.H. I wonder what am I doing wrong because when I test this new code I get slower results than what I get with my old code?....I made a random 20000-by-2 matrix and gave it as input both to my own and your code and mine was faster? :O My code took 4.9 seconds and yours 7.9 seconds on my computer....

Comment: I posted the comparison of your and my code...why is mine better?....how did you get 50x faster?  =) Thank you for your help!

Comment: Interesting! I did not save the code as a function, but instead executed it as part of a script in "cell mode". Somehow that had a huge impact on your implementation, and very little on mine. When I save both as a function, your implementation is faster as well. I guess there is some pre-compilation of functions going on in the background. In principle, it's always better to vectorize code in Matlab, that is, to ditch for loops. This is the first example that I saw where it is the other way around!

Comment: Thank you for your comment and advice. I will try to apply your advice from now on. Strange thing indeed :D

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your final goal is to improve the runtime performance and if you have good enough memory to run a vectorized approach, this could be one of those -

```
%// Column arrays
c1 = predval(:,1);
c2 = predval(:,2);

%// Get logical arrays of IF conditional statements in the original code
start_cond = bsxfun(@ne,c2,c2.')               %//'# starting condition

%// Rest of the three IF conditionals
case1 = bsxfun(@lt,c1,c1.') & bsxfun(@lt,c2,c2.') | ...
    bsxfun(@gt,c1,c1.') & bsxfun(@gt,c2,c2.')  %//'
case2 = bsxfun(@lt,c1,c1.') & bsxfun(@gt,c2,c2.') | ...
    bsxfun(@gt,c1,c1.') & bsxfun(@lt,c2,c2.')  %//'
case3 = bsxfun(@eq,c1,c1.')                    %//'

%// Get the counts for different cases and finally get the output sum
w1 = start_cond & case1
w2 = start_cond & ~case1 & ~case2 & case3
hSum = sum(w1(:))./2 + sum(w2(:))./4
```

Comment: Hi @Divakar do you also get better results with Martin J.H.'s code? In my computer I get worse running time for some reason....I posted the comparison above....any idea why mine is faster?

Comment: @jjepsuomi Ah! I didn't benchmark against yours earlier. But as now I did, your original approach seem to be the fastest! Well, I just tested against the GPU version of my code running on NVIDIA GTX 750 Ti and it was quite faster than your original one, so if you have some NVIDIA GPU, it could help you out, otherwise stick with your original one.